# ARIMA, VAR and State Space Model (SSM) forecasting comparison

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, vector-autoregression, state-space-models

I am trying to compare the asset price forecasting abilities of SSMs with ARIMA and VAR models. To keep it brief, this is the plan that I am following:

1. Collect multivariate data
2. Perform ADF stationarity test on the data, apply differencing where needed
3. Estimate a VAR model on the differenced data
4. Perform Granger causality test, select variables that Granger causes the forecast variable or is very close to doing so
5. Estimate ARIMA model
6. Perform forecast of ARIMA and VAR, and back-difference to original scale (price), calculate RMSE
7. Calibrate SSM (univariate and multi-variate through identification)
8. Forecast using the SSM with the original undifferenced data, since SSMs do not require stationary series, and calculate RMSE
9. Compare results

In an overall brief sense, this is what I am currently doing. It's my first time working with such models, and I am therefore interested in getting input. Does it make sense, or is something missing?

**Edit:**

The SSM is a LTI SSM with Deterministic and Stochastic elements, given by the equations:

[image]

Where the Stochastic elements matrices C and F can be used to find the Kalman gain matrix K by:

K = CF^-1

The VAR and ARIMA models use their standard formulations

Comment: SSM is a broad class of models. E.g. ARIMA and VAR also have SSM representations. What is your SSM (and makes it different from ARIMA or VAR)?

Comment: I'm using a Linear Time Invariant SSM from control theory, while the ARIMA and VAR are using their classical representations

Comment: The representation does not matter in the sense that changing the representation does not change the model. The fact that ARIMA and VAR have SSM representations means you can compare them quite directly to the linear time invariant SSM. Now, is LTI SSM not just a special case of ARIMA or vector ARIMA? They look quite similar to me.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the SSM representations of VAR and ARIMA, but wouldn't the underlying assumptions of stationarity still stand? The LTI SSM doesn't have the restriction of requiring stationarity, and this is one of the things I want to check in a practical comparison. The LTI SSM handles non-stationarity by having both deterministic and stochastic components, as far as I know.

Comment: Could you write down the model equation(s) of LTI SSM (perhaps by editing the post)? Regarding the deterministic components, you can add these to ARIMA or VAR quite easily, so again I wonder if we have 3 unique models here or just 2.

Comment: Hi, sure thing! Added an edit now, let me know if more information is needed :)

Comment: Thanks! What are u and e in the formulas? I suppose e is just the error term but what exactly is u?

Comment: The formulation stems from control theory, so 'u' is input data and 'e' is the error term as you mention, 'x' are the states and 'y' are the outputs

Comment: OK, to me that looks very much like just another representation of ARMA (univariate or multivariate). I do not quite see anything beyond additive AR and MA terms here.

Comment: Hi: Note that $u_t$ denotes the control variable in control theory so you won't want to include that in the state space formulation. As Richard mentioned, there is an equivalence between ARIMA and state space so, if you're not careful, you will be comparing apples and apples. For example, ARIMA(0,1,1) is random walk + noise in state space and ARIMA(0,2,2) is local linear trend. In general, you can go between one and the other but it's not always obvious.

Comment: Yes, they seem very similar. In that case however, is one of the only caveats that the SSM doesn't require stationary series?